# Get json message from soap response in wso2

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

```
...
<property expression="//soap:Envelope/soap:Body/Response/Result" name="result"/>
<log>
  <property expression="get-property('result')" name="result"/>
</log>
...
```

**the response**

```
...
<response>  [  { "_id": "62908b4267c5284f7fa8320e",  "index": 0, "serial": "11006883-fb2b-49ba-a6f7-0ec0daafa1c5", "Active": false, "balance": "$3,723.68", ,"age": 34 }]    </response>
```

How do i get the response property for id and balance?
When i use

```
 <log>
    <property expression="get-property('response')" name="response"/>
 </log>
```

**it only returns the Json array only only**

Comment: Can you elaborate on your question? Are you getting a Json message embedded within an XML response? Also what's the content type of the response message?

Comment: Yes the Jason is inside the xml, and it's xml content type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can assume payload look like below.

```
    <response>
[
    {
        "_id": "62908b4267c5284f7fa8320e",
        "index": 0,
        "serial": "11006883-fb2b-49ba-a6f7-0ec0daafa1c5",
        "Active": false,
        "balance": "$3,723.68",
        "age": 34
    }
]
</response>
```

We're going to store `<response>` tag values into property like below.

```
<property name="jsonMessageContent" expression="//response/text()"/>
```

Post that, going to use `enrich` mediator to convert property value into body.

```
<enrich>
        <source clone="false" xpath="get-property('jsonMessageContent')"/>
        <target type="body"/>
     </enrich>
```

Finally we can use `xpath` to fetch values like `_id,balance` from payload

```
<log level="custom">
        <property name="id value***" expression="//jsonArray/jsonElement/_id/text()"/>
        <property name="balance value***" expression="//jsonArray/jsonElement/balance/text()"/>
     </log>
```

Output:

```
id value*** = 62908b4267c5284f7fa8320e, balance value*** = $3,723.68
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a valid Json within your XML response. You can do the following to get the ID and balance. Here you have to use a script mediator.

```
<property expression="//response/text()" name="jsonMessageContent"/>
<script language="nashornJs"><![CDATA[
// Get the Json message portion from the response. You can use property mediator extract only that part      
mc.getProperty('jsonMessageContent')
// Convert into a Json Object
var jsonObj = JSON.parse(mc.getProperty('jsonMessageContent'));
// Specify your jsonpath here and extract
var balance = jsonObj.balance;

// Set to a different property  so you can use it in your integrations
mc.setProperty("balance", balance);
]]></script>
```